# Python subprocesses experience mysterious delay in receiving stdin EOF

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I reduced a problem I was seeing in my application down into the following test case. In this code, a parent process concurrently spawns 2 (you can spawn more) subprocesses that read a big message from the parent over stdin, sleep for 5 seconds, and write something back. However, there's unexpected waiting happening somewhere, causing the code to complete in 10 seconds instead of the expected 5.

If you set `verbose=True`, you can see that the straggling subprocess is receiving most of the messages, then waiting for the last chunk of 3 chars---it's not detecting that the pipe has been closed. Furthermore, if I simply don't do anything with the second process (`doreturn=True`), the first process will *never* see the EOF.

Any ideas what's happening? Further down is some example output. Thanks in advance.

```
from subprocess import *
from threading import *
from time import *
from traceback import *
import sys
verbose = False
doreturn = False
msg = (20*4096+3)*'a'
def elapsed(): return '%7.3f' % (time() - start)
if sys.argv[1:]:
  start = float(sys.argv[2])
  if verbose:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: sys.stdin.read(4096), ''):
      print >> sys.stderr, '..', time(), sys.argv[1], 'read', len(chunk)
  else:
    sys.stdin.read()
  print >> sys.stderr, elapsed(), '..', sys.argv[1], 'done reading'
  sleep(5)
  print msg
else:
  start = time()
  def go(i):
    print elapsed(), i, 'starting'
    p = Popen(['python','stuckproc.py',str(i), str(start)], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    if doreturn and i == 1: return
    print elapsed(), i, 'writing'
    p.stdin.write(msg)
    print elapsed(), i, 'closing'
    p.stdin.close()
    print elapsed(), i, 'reading'
    p.stdout.read()
    print elapsed(), i, 'done'
  ts = [Thread(target=go, args=(i,)) for i in xrange(2)]
  for t in ts: t.start()
  for t in ts: t.join()
```

Example output:

```
  0.001 0 starting
  0.003 1 starting
  0.005 0 writing
  0.016 1 writing
  0.093 0 closing
  0.093 0 reading
  0.094 1 closing
  0.094 1 reading
  0.098 .. 1 done reading
  5.103 1 done
  5.108 .. 0 done reading
 10.113 0 done
```

I'm using Python 2.6.5 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After way too much time, I figured it out, after a quote from [this post](http://fixunix.com/questions/379652-sending-eof-named-pipe.html) jumped out at me:

> See the "I/O on Pipes and FIFOs" section of pipe(7) ("man 7 pipe")
>
> "If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have
>   been closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see
>   end-of-file (read(2) will return 0)."

I should've known this, but it never occurred to me - had nothing to do with Python in particular. What was happening was: the subprocesses were getting forked with open (writer) file descriptors to each others' pipes. As long as there are open writer file descriptors to a pipe, readers won't see EOF.

E.g.:

```
p1=Popen(..., stdin=PIPE, ...) # creates a pipe the parent process can write to
p2=Popen(...) # inherits the writer FD - as long as p2 exists, p1 won't see EOF
```

Turns out there's a `close_fds` parameter to `Popen`, so the solution is to pass `close_fds=True`. All simple and obvious in hindsight, but still managed to cost at least a couple eyeballs good chunks of time.