# Help with ping via Popen

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, popen, ping

I'm developing a software to monitor communication to different locations.
the principle is simple: send ping every second and display the results in real time (ms delay, packet loss etc)

It's also important to mention that I'm running the software from Linux, so in order to ping from my software i choose the subporocess.Popen way, because opening sockets require you to be logged as root user. And i don't want to give everyone root access to the server..

Here is the class reponsible for the pinging:

```
 class WorkerThread(QThread):
  def __init__(self,receiver,sitename):
    QThread.__init__(self)

    global time_manager
    time_manager[sitename] = [time.time(),0,0] #for statistic purpeses

    self.stopped = 0
    self.receiver = receiver
    self.sitename = sitename


  def run(self):
    icmp_count = 0
    ping_result = ""
    packeloss_result = ""

    while not self.stopped:
       data = subprocess.Popen("ping -c1 "+str(sites[self.sitename]),shell = True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       data.wait()
       time_manager[self.sitename][1] +=1 #counts the icmps sent 
       bufferdata = data.stdout.read() 
       ping_result = ms_pat.findall(bufferdata)
       packeloss_result = packetloss_pat.findall(bufferdata)

       if ping_result:
         ping_ms = ping_result[0][0]
       if packeloss_result:
         time_manager[self.sitename][2] +=1        
         ping_ms = "-1"

       ms_count[self.sitename].append(float(ping_ms))
       time.sleep(1)
       event = QCustomEvent(12345)
       event.setData(self.sitename+ping_ms)
       QApplication.postEvent(self.receiver, event)

  def stop(self):
    self.stopped = 1
```

I'm using threads because sometimes i need to run multiple ping jobs to different sites.

My problem is this:
when running, i get the ms delay results perfectly, but every few pings i get a not accurate result, higher then what it actually should be.

I know that the results are not accurate, because i run ping from a console at the same time, and there i don't get that ping spike

Example:

ping_ms = 20.0

ping_ms = 21.31

ping_ms = 23.23

**ping_ms = 80.2**

ping_ms = 23.23

ping_ms = 24.2

I don't understand why this is happening. maybe i need to write the code differently. if someone could help me, it will be much appreciated.

thanks.

**i have isolated the problem:**

It seems that the problem is not in the code, but in the OS or in the ping command itself.
when i run manually every second in console the command: "ping -c1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" after few attempts i get the same result ,a weird ping spike. but if the ping fluent "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", there are no spikes.

Is it possible to run fluent ping with Popen from a script and read the results?

Comment: Why do you think the latency spike isn't accurate? There could be tons of points of delay between you and the host.

Comment: because i run ping from console at the same time, and there i don't get the ping spike

Comment: @Urban48, that doesn't seem very conclusive to me; I see no reason why two pings, even if they occur nearly simultaneously, should _necessarily_ give the same result. Is it that you _never_ get a spike from the console, but only from the script?

Comment: yes, the ping at console is very steady, with not a single spike, while the script gives me spikes every few seconds. the difference is very noticeable.

Comment: Have you tried using this without the shell=True?  e.g.: data = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/ping", "-c1", "+str(sites[self.sitename])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: without the shell=True, i get OSError: no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `close_fds=True` to your `Popen` call (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940607/python-subprocesses-experience-mysterious-delay-in-receiving-stdin-eof)). If you have other pipes open in other threads, it may be the case that they are interacting somehow (forcing a particular ordering of threads). Consider using `Popen.communicate()` rather than reading from the process' stdout stream directly. With that said, it seems unlikely that your ping implementation would return different readings based on how well its output is being buffered.

At a higher level, you should keep in mind that ping timing data is inherently unreliable. If you can't fix the spike, and you're convinced it is an artefact from the `Popen` call (rather than just random noise), then it is probably reasonable to post-process the data. For example, you could collect 5 datapoints at a time and take the median. (Note that the median is less sensitive to outliers than the average). This is no worse than what `ping` is already doing.

**Update 26/02**

Sorry to hear ^ didn't help. Couple of other ideas:

**1.** It might be helpful if we know a bit more about how you're running `ping` from the shell. In python, you're using `-c1` to limit `ping` to a single try. I am guessing that, in the shell, you are simply running `ping hostname` and watching the results in real time -- is this true? If so, please try running a bash script as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in {1..50}
do
   ping -c1 somehostname
   # maybe 'sleep 1' here
done
```

And look very carefully at the results. It is possible that the spikes are the result of how you're calling `ping`.

**2.** Your sample code doesn't have your regex definitions. Are you 100% sure they are capturing the exact right values from ping's output?

Comment: thank you for the answer, close_fds=True, didn't help.
Its very weird. If i run multiple ping jobs, some times they all get this spike at the same time, and sometimes only part of them. but it happens every few seconds. the spikes are big: like form 20ms delay to 140ms.

i thought about what you offerd with post-process, but i need to display my results as real-time as possible.

So i guess opening sockets and sending pings manual is the way to go, but its a bit of a problem in Linux.

Comment: Updated the answer to add a few additional ideas that might help you get to the bottom of this. Good luck!

Comment: you first suggestion made it clear that the problem is not in the code! I tried what you suggested with the bash script, and i got the same ping spike, witch means the problem is with the OS or ping command itself. when ping fluent its spike free, when ping used with -c or -w i get the ping spike. how can i go around it?

Comment: I'm glad to hear you've been able to isolate the problem. I recommend the following: run ping with `-c2`. Then from the output under `--- hostname statistics ---` extract the `rtt min` field (the first number). This has three advantages: (1) it may not exhibit as many spikes, and (2) even if there are spikes, you are unlikely to see them because you are picking the `min`, and (3) you are launching fewer processes, and thus reducing overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good starting point:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ping/0.1

Of course, it's not clear that there is any problem with what you're doing now really.  Since the ping time is being parsed from the output of ping it's not like we can blame process spawning overhead or something.

Comment: tnx for you answer. using the open sockets method is working better then popen. It seems that i don't get the ping spikes. but i try to avoid that. giving root to a python script is not very smart.

Comment: My comment about setuid is incorrect so I removed it.  To actually get a python script to run as root you'd have to setuid the python interpreter as well and that's a terrible idea.  Sorry :-(